# Implementing new tag for version 4 of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, version-tags

Esri recently released version 4 of the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API - see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/ and https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/choose-version/index.html

This is a substantial re-write compared to version 3.x with seemingly every class, method and event receiving an update. There are also new functions relating to 3D web maps.

Errors, questions and problems for this version are likely to be different compared to version 3.x.  Do we need a new GIS-SE tag to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We all seem to be in agreement, so I have created tags for [arcgis-javascript-api-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-3) and [arcgis-javascript-api-4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4) to accompany [arcgis-javascript-api-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-2) while leaving [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api) in place.

I suggest that use of [arcgis-javascript-api-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-3) and [arcgis-javascript-api-4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4) be encouraged and that [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api) no longer be used.

When [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api) questions are edited for other purposes I would encourage replacement of the generic tag with the appropriate version tag but I see no need for systematic retagging.

If you need to find all ArcGIS API for JavaScript questions type `[arcgis-javascript-api*]` into the search bar which explodes it out to search all four tags at once.