# Synonymizing ArcGIS API for JavaScript version tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, version-tags

In [Implementing new tag for version 4 of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4239) it looked like the community wanted (or at least were not suggesting any alternatives) to phasing out the [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api) tag (1,558 questions) in favour of version tagging with [arcgis-javascript-api-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-2) (3 questions), [arcgis-javascript-api-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-3) (167 questions) and [arcgis-javascript-api-4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4) (82 questions) instead.

Since then I have noticed that [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api) continues to be applied to new questions both on its own, and in combination with one or more version tags.

Should we continue trying to implement version tags on ArcGIS API for JavaScript questions as per the earlier Meta Q&A, roll them all back into [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api), or do something else?

Answer (score 3):

Given that:

- there are only 3 questions tagged as [arcgis-javascript-api-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-2)
- there are only 167 questions tagged as [arcgis-javascript-api-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-3)
- these are mostly synonymous with [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api)

it might make sense to roll the `2` and `3` tags into [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api) if this is possible.

However, version 4 of the ArcGIS JavaScript API seems to be substantially different to the previous versions, with most classes and functions apparently re-written from scratch. So [arcgis-javascript-api-4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4) should remain as a separate tag.

For version 4 questions, I'd suggest that the tag [arcgis-javascript-api-4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4) on its own makes it pretty clear which version and software are being used.