# Do we need to rename the ArcGIS JavaScript API tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Esri have once again decided to rename an existing product - the API previously known as the ArcGIS JavaScript API is now the [ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/).

[image]

Do we need to rename the [[arcgis-javascript-api-4]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4) tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that tag needs a rename, which moderators can do by using their merge tool. That tool optionally makes synonyms of the old names which are merged.

I propose that we create a new tag named [arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript) with these tags to be made synonyms of it:

- [arcgis-javascript-api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api) (2,034 questions)
- [arcgis-javascript-api-4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4) (279 questions)

We discussed the value of the [arcgis-javascript-api-4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4) tag staying separate at [Synonymizing ArcGIS API for JavaScript version tags](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/how-many-arcgis-api-for-javascript-tags-are-needed).  Since that time, I have gone further away from seeing any value in version tags because I think all version information should be included within the question body instead.